# Call class contructor before trait's constructor in scala

Tags: scala, traits

I have this scenario

```
trait D {
    def someMethod(): Unit = {}
  }

  trait C {
    val locations: Seq[Int]

    someSomethingWithLocations() // calling this in constructor

    def someSomethingWithLocations(): Unit = {
      print(locations.length)
    }
  }

  class B extends D with C {
    override val locations: Seq[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
    someMethod()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val b = new B
  }
```

When I run this code `someSomethingWithLocations` throws null pointer exception because constructor of class B is not called yet, hence locations is not initialized.
And If I change declaration of class B to

```
      class B extends{
        override val locations: Seq[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
        someMethod()
      } with D with C
```

compiler complains that someMethod() is not found. How can i resolve this issue?

For now I have moved declaration of locations to a different trait and my program works as expected but I would like to avoid unnecessary trait if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you tried is so called *early initializer*. You can't call `someMethod` inside it, because:

- early initializers can only contain `val` definitions
- the trait `D` which contains `someMethod` is mixed in *after* the early initializer, so it can't be used yet

But anyway, early initializers should be considered a last resort when fixing initialization order. Before falling back to it, you should first try some less hacky solutions:

1. Instead of defining or overriding a `val` from trait, try making it a constructor parameter. Constructor parameters which are `val`s are initialized before any constructor code is invoked. Here you can do it by introducing an intermediate abstract class:

   ```
   abstract class AbstractB(val locations: Seq[Int])
   class B extends AbstractB(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil) with D with C {
     someMethod()
   }
   ```
2. Make your `val` a `lazy val`:

   ```
   class B extends D with C {
     override lazy val locations: Seq[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
     someMethod()
   }
   ```

   This way `locations` will be initialized not in the constructor of `class B` but simply on first access, which in your case will be the constructor of `trait C` (note that in this case the `lazy` keyword makes the field be initialized *earlier* than normally rather than *later*, which is a common intuition about `lazy val`s).

   `lazy val` seems like a simple and easy solution, but I would recommend first trying constructor parameters if possible. This is because the `lazy val` itself may access another `val` which may not yet be initialized at that point. This way the problem escalates to other `val`s and in the end you may find yourself having to declare all of them as `lazy`.
3. If you still want to use an early initializer, you need to move the method call outside of it and put it into constructor:

   ```
   class B extends {
     override val locations: Seq[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
   } with D with C {
     someMethod()
   }
   ```